# Russian charset in spring form

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I'm new in spring-mvc. I have a project with Spring Controllers + JSP. Now my problem is I have broken charset in  POST data. I have read many posts dedicated this problem - added filters to spring filter chain in my Bootstrap:

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encoding-filter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
    encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
```

added message converter withs WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
{
    converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<>());
}
```

but nothing helps me. If I post form data with russian charset - it comes broken to controller.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some investigations I found that problem only appears in my custom Spring Security AuthService. The problem was solved after adding CharacterEncodingFilter in security filter chain.